# Typescript [number, number] vs number[]

Tags: typescript

Can someone help me understand why I get a type error with the following code:

```ts
function sumOfTwoNumbersInArray(a: [number, number]) {
    return a[0] + a[1];
}

sumOfTwoNumbersInArray([1, 2]); // Works

let foo = [1, 2];
sumOfTwoNumbersInArray(foo); // Error
```

The error is:

> Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[number, number]'.
>
> Type 'number[]' is missing the following properties from type '[number, number]': 0, 1

Comment: The parameter type is a tuple while `foo` is an array of numbers. The compiler plays it safe and assigns the least restrictive type. Passing one for the other gives this error. If `foo` is meant to be a tuple, you should type it explicitly: `let foo: [number, number] = [1,2];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter `a` in `sumOfTwoNumbersInArray` is a tuple.
It is not the same as `number[]`.

The following works okay because all variables are basic arrays

```
function sumOfTwoNumbersInArray(a: number[]) { // parameter declared as array
  return a[0] + a[1];
}

let foo = [1, 2]; // initialization defaults to array

sumOfTwoNumbersInArray(foo); // no error.
```

As Rafael mentioned, explicitly defining foo as a tuple works fine as well.

```
function sumOfTwoNumbersInArray(a: [number, number]) { // parameter declared as a tuple
  return a[0] + a[1];
}

let foo: [number, number] = [1, 2]; // variable explicitely defined as a tuple

sumOfTwoNumbersInArray(foo); // no error.
```

Answer (score 1):

In most cases when people create an array they want it to have dynamic size, so the type is `number[]`.

In newer TS you should be able to do this to get constant size typing:

```
let foo = [1, 2] as const;
```

This may prevent changing the array, though. So if you want that you need to explicitly use `[number, number]` as type annotation.